# Subqueries (in / exists) to Joins

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, in-subquery

```
SELECT *, `o_cheque_request.member_id`, `o_cheque_request.wallet_id`
FROM `o_cheque_request`, `o_member`, o_memberinfo`
WHERE `o_cheque_request.member_id` = `o_member.member_id`
AND `o_member.member_id` = `o_memberinfo.member_id`
AND withdraw_date >='2012-07-21'
AND `o_cheque_request.member_id`
IN (SELECT `member_id` FROM `o_cheque_request` GROUP BY `member_id` HAVING SUM(gross_amount ) <=10000)
GROUP BY `o_cheque_request.withdraw_date`, `o_cheque_request.member_id` ORDER BY `request_id` DESC
```

this takes to much time around 29 seconds how to reduce...using join... Guys please help me... Table Structure for **o_cheque_request**
`request_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`wallet_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`member_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `withdraw_date` date default NULL,
  `amount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `gross_amount` float(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `admin_charge` float(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `tds` float(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `repurchase` float(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `net_amount` float(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `withdraw_type` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `bank_name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `cheque_no` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `courier_name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `tracking_no` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `cheque_date` date default '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`request_id`),
  KEY `member_id` (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4738 ;

Comment: 29 secs to fetch how many records? and please provide your table structure.

Comment: Hey I have more than 4000 entries in o_cheque_request table...

Comment: Please provide table structure in proper way and for three tables with their internal relations which you have used in query.

Comment: Each Table have common field name member_id which connects them

Answer (score 0):

TRY WITH THIS

```
 SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *, `o_cheque_request.member_id`, `o_cheque_request.wallet_id`
        FROM `o_cheque_request`
        JOIN `o_member` ON `o_cheque_request.member_id` = `o_member.member_id`
        JOIN `o_memberinfo` ON `o_member.member_id` = `o_memberinfo.member_id`
        WHERE withdraw_date >='2012-07-21'
        GROUP BY `o_cheque_request.member_id` HAVING SUM(`o_cheque_request.gross_amount` ) <=10000
    ) AS T
    GROUP BY `withdraw_date`, `member_id` ORDER BY `request_id` DESC
```

Comment: thanks for reply but got **error** :: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
        SELECT *, `o_cheque_request.member_id`, `o_cheque_request.wal' at line 1